# Calc number of weeks between two dates in SQL Server Round Up

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

How does one calculate difference in weeks between two dates that is rounded up.

This means even if there is 1 day between the two dates it is counted as "Week".

Is there an improved version of `datediff(ww, Date1, Date2)` where it allows parameters so that we can choose whether to round up/down?

One way I thought of doing it is to calculate "Days" between two dates, divide that number by 7 days, and if remainder exists, add another day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you've thought of (divide by 7 and round up).

Comment: `( Days + 6 ) / 7`. In general: `( Things + ThingsPerGroup - 1 ) / ThingsPerGroup` using integer division. One Thing pushes the sum up to `ThingsPerGroup` and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @dt1 datetime = '2016-01-01'
declare @dt2 datetime = '2016-01-07'
select ceiling(convert(float, abs(datediff(day, @dt1, @dt2))) / 7)
```

Comment: Thanks that's something similar that I had.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1 = '2016-04-24'
SET @Date2 = '2016-05-09'

SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,@Date1,@Date2))/7 +
    CASE DATEDIFF(dd,@Date1,@Date2)%7 WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good way of doing it :) Thanks for helping out.